# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while receiving image data from NSStream swift

Tags: swift, http, nsstream, payload, nsinputstream

I am sending a message to NSOutputStream to get image data as a payload in http response.

```
let bufferSize = 999999

case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:

        if (inputStream == aStream) {
            var buffer = [UInt8](count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)

            var out: NSString = ""
            while (self.inputStream!.hasBytesAvailable){
                var bytesRead: Int! = inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
                if bytesRead >= 0 {

                    out = out.stringByAppendingString(NSString(bytes: buffer, length: bytesRead, encoding: encoding)! as String)


                    status = true
                } else {
                    println("# error")
                }
                println("> \(_data) ------- \n \(out)")
            }
        }
```

In this line of code i am getting fatal error

> out = out.stringByAppendingString(NSString(bytes: buffer, length:
>   bytesRead, encoding: encoding)! as String)

Expected result ::

HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 154837\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n**IMAGE_DATA**

How can i get that IMAGE DATA..

Comment: In the `if` statement did you mean `if let inputStream = aStream`?

Comment: @flashadvanced : No, inputStream is NSInputStream... like this var inputStream : NSInputStream?

Comment: I think your `inputStream` is nil. Put a break point and check this.

Comment: @flashadvanced: No inputStream was not nil, i am getting bytesRead value also [878715]